# Are instance methods duplicated in memory for each object?

Tags: c#, class, oop

To be more clear about my question, if you create an array of a particular class: for example,

```
ExampleClass[] test = new ExampleClass[5];
```

I know the five `ExampleClass` instances would create a copy of each variable for each class, but are the methods/functions duplicated 5 times in memory, or do each of the tests just point to the same single class codebase? If it duplicated for each class, that would just be a waste of memory.

Comment: Could you please post code that looks correct? `ExampleClass test=new test[5]` looks very strange.

Comment: Allocating an array does not allocate class instances. Whether using arrays or not, multiple instances of a class all use the same executable code and static data members; only the _instance_ data members (i.e. fields) are given new copies for each instance of the class. If you want a more specific answer than that, post a valid C# code example and explain precisely what you want to know. As it is now, it's very hard to understand for sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every type loaded into an AppDomain will have a **Method Table** structure that holds every method that type defines, plus the virtual methods derived from parent (typically **Object**) and the methods defined by any implemented interface.

This Method Table is pointed by every instance of that object. So every instance **does not duplicate** all the methods defined by that type, but **points to this method table structure with a reference**.

For example:

```
 public class MyClass : IDisposable
 {
        private static void MyStaticMethod()
        {
            // ....
        }
        public void MyInstanceMethod()
        {
            // ....
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
 }
```

This MyClass will have a method table including:

- MyStaticMethod
- MyInstanceMethod
- Dispose
- And other virtual methods derived from System.Object

Have a look at nice diagram of method table:

[image: Method Table Diagram]

You can check the whole article about method tables [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx)

Comment: Is this method table ever unloaded from memory? e.g. if the garbage collector has cleaned all instances of a certain type - will that type's method table still stick in memory?