# Memory allocation under Methods in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, allocation

I'm still learning C# and I'm under difficult case understanding memory allocation in methods.
Let's imagine the situation that I got some reference object, and in a method I'm assigning existing object, what will be done in memory?

I found [Are instance methods duplicated in memory for each object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751624/are-instance-methods-duplicated-in-memory-for-each-object) but it is not so clear for me in case that I describe.
Any other references will be very much appreciated.

```cs
public class ClassToBeAssigned : IClassToBeAssigned {}
public interface IClassToBeAssigned{}

public class AllocatingClass
{
  private ClassToBeAssigned testAssigment;

  // Just as example
  void Main()
  {
       // new allocation in memory
       testAssigment = new ClassToBeAssigned();
       Assign(testAssigment);
  }

  // create here copy of context by assigned
  void Assign(IClassToBeAssigned assigned)
  {
       // What will happend now if there are 4x method calls ?
       DoSomething(assigned);
       DoSomething(assigned);
       DoSomething(assigned);
       DoSomething(assigned);
  }
  void DoSomething(IClassToBeAssigned assignIt)
  {
       // What is happening here in memory allocation for that reference each call ?
       IClassToBeAssigned dealWithIt = assignIt;
  }
}
```

I just got a bit confused about what is happening there, also I found lots of information, but nothing for this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a reference doesn't create a copy in C#. You only create a new instance in `Main`, so there's only one instance of `ClassToBeAssigned`.

The exception is with value types; these need special care. If `ClassToBeAssigned` was a `struct` rather than a `class`, each call of `Assign(testAssignment);` would in fact create a new instance that is a copy of `testAssignment`. Note that even in this case, `DoSomething(assignment);` will *not* result in a new copy. If you want to understand more about this topic, read up on boxing in C#.

As for `DoSomething`, it does absolutely nothing, so it's not clear what you would expect to happen there :)

Answer (score 0):

`DoSomething` would allocate some bytes from the stack for the `dealWithIt` variable, so depending on the system that would be 32 or 64 bits it allocates, since `dealWithIt` is just a reference.
The reference from `assignIt` would then be copied to that allocated memory, to then be immediately be released again, since the method is done and the stack moves back to the previous method.